# ENOENT: no such file or directory error in Cypress

Tags: node.js, typescript, ubuntu, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

When running Cypress using GUI, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/user/.config/Cypress/cy/production/projects/testProject-ba4506b83588731a9b974658caac8b40/bundles/cypress/e2e/01-test-details.feature'
```

When running using CLI, I get this error:

> Running: 01-test-details.feature (1 of 8)
>
> Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:
>
> cypress/e2e/01-test-details.feature
>
> The error was:
>
> Error: Build failed with 14 errors:
>
> cypress/support/step-definitions/01-01-test-details.hooks.ts:1:30:
> ERROR: Could not resolve "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor"
> cypress/support/step-definitions/01-test-details.steps.ts:1:21: ERROR:
> Could not resolve "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor"
> cypress/support/utilities/date-util.ts:1:19: ERROR: Could not resolve
> "moment" ... at failureErrorWithLog
> (/home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1650:15)
> at
> /home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1059:25
> at runOnEndCallbacks
> (/home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1485:45)
> at buildResponseToResult
> (/home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1057:7)
> at
> /home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1086:16
> at responseCallbacks.
> (/home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:703:9)
> at handleIncomingPacket
> (/home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:763:9)
> at Socket.readFromStdout
> (/home/user/project/Cypress_Project/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:679:7)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28) at Socket.emit
> (node:domain:488:12) at addChunk
> (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12) at
> readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3) at
> Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5) at
> Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
>
> This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code.
> This is usually caused by:
>
> - A missing file or dependency
> - A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies
>
> Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.

But these packages are installed properly. But this project location doesn't contain a `bundles` folder.

```
/home/user/.config/Cypress/cy/production/projects/testProject-ba4506b83588731a9b974658caac8b40
```

Node Version: v21.2.0

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Yarn version: 1.22.19

Cypress Version: ^13.5.1

Answer (score 2):

When respective test file was selected to be run in the cypress runner, it popped the same message- "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory".

Please refer to the PROBLEMS tab of your IDE (VS Code), it has the problem and line number for you to investigate. Refer image attached.

[image: PROBLEMS tab of your IDE (VS Code)]

Comment: Thanks Atul! I had to reset Ubuntu to fix the issue. I think it was due to some incorrect installation of dependencies. But this is helpful. Next time I'll check the Problems tab to see the issue.